# Swap elements between arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove items from one array and add then to another. At some stage I will then add them back to the original array. When I run the array 10 times the 10th time does not return the expected result of full array = 0 remove array = 100; Anyone know why this would be the case?

```
 var fullArr = [];//contains all items
 var remArr = [];//contains removed items
 var userAnswer = true;//this would be user input

 populateArray();
 runTenTimes();
 //getting the answer right 10 times should result in fullArr.length = 0; remArr.length = 100;

 function runTenTimes(){
     for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
     //console.log(i);
     checkUserAnswer();   
     }
 }
 function populateArray(){
     for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
         fullArr.push(i);
     }
 }

function checkUserAnswer(){
     if(userAnswer){//only if true
         for(i=0;i<10;i++){//10 because I remove 10 at a time
           removeShape(fullArr,fullArr[i],remArr);
         }
     }else{
          // add elements from remove arr
          // back into full array   
     }
     console.log("full array : " + fullArr.length);
     console.log("remove array : " + remArr.length);
     console.log("------------------")
 }

 function removeShape(arr,item,rem){
      for(var i = 0;i<arr.length; i++) {
           if(arr[i] === item) {
             rem.push(arr[i]);
             arr.splice(i, 1);
           }
      }   
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/non_tech_guy/vy671jv4/

Comment: You're changing the array while looping over it. A simple way to solve this problem is to use `forEach`, which makes a copy of the array.

Comment: Thanks, it still produced an error until I added arr.shift(). Now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please use this code

```
var fullArr = [];//contains all items
 var remArr = [];//contains removed items
 var userAnswer = true;//this would be user input

 populateArray();
 runTenTimes();
 //getting the answer right 10 times should result in fullArr.length = 0; remArr.length = 100;

 function runTenTimes(){
     for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
     //console.log(i);
     checkUserAnswer();   
     }
 }
 function populateArray(){
     for(var i=0;i<100;i++){
         fullArr.push(i);
     }
 }

function checkUserAnswer(){
     if(userAnswer){//only if true
         var arrCopy = fullArr.slice(0);
         for(i=0;i<10;i++){//10 because I remove 10 at a time
           removeShape(fullArr,arrCopy[i],remArr);
         }
     }else{
          // add elements from remove arr
          // back into full array   
     }
     console.log("full array : " + fullArr.length);
     console.log("remove array : " + remArr.length);
     console.log("------------------")
 }

 function removeShape(arr,item,rem){
      for(var i = 0;i<arr.length; i++) {
           if(arr[i] === item) {
             rem.push(arr[i]);
             arr.splice(i, 1);
           }
      }   
 }
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted to do. It does not produce any reference errors to objects in the array. Many thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

changing to forEach still produced a error until I changed arr.shift() rather than arr.splice(i,0).

```
function removeShape(arr,item,rem){
      arr.forEach(function(){
        if(arr[i] === item) {
             rem.push(arr.shift());
          }
       })
}
```